# Chris Manning is amazing" and labels "PER PER O O" would become ([[1,9], [2,9], [3,8], [4,8]], [1, 1, 4, 4]). how "chris" is encoded in [1,9]?

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition

how "chris" is encoded in [1,9] ?  Below is code link

https://github.com/roypan/CS224n/blob/master/assignment3/q2_rnn.py

data: is a list of (sentence, labels) tuples. @sentence is a list
            containing the words in the sentence and @label is a list of
            output labels. Each word is itself a list of
            @n_features features. For example, the sentence "Chris
            Manning is amazing" and labels "PER PER O O" would become
            ([[1,9], [2,9], [3,8], [4,8]], [1, 1, 4, 4]). Here "Chris"
            the word has been featurized as "[1, 9]", and "[1, 1, 4, 4]"
            is the list of labels.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you turn words into vectors by accessing a lookup table.  Each word is mapped to a distinct vector.  These vectors are generated through a training process the creates word embeddings.

An example of this wold be GloVe:

https://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/glove/